# Talend Job in Cloud gets Illegal Character Error, but not in studio

Tags: talend

## Description of Problem

I run a job on my local Talend Studio and it works.
When I publish it to Cloud and run it on a remote engine; 
I get an illegal character error.

- Note: The Windows Remote server is running on the same machine the Remote Engine is running.  They resolve to the same resource.

## What I tried

1. One other job runs on the remote engine being used (STG)
2. The remote engine and Talend Studio are the same machines for STG
3. I tried moving the concatenation to a tSetGlobal var and that did not work - same error
4. I also tried using java.net.URLEncoder.encode() but got a different error that the URL was not absolute

## Error produced in the cloud

```
"Illegal character in scheme name"
```

[image: Screenshot of error produced in the cloud]

## Configuration of Componenet in Error

[image: Screenshot of tRest_2 component configuration]

## Console from Talend Studio with Job working

[image]

Comment: I think it may have something to do with the Parameters of the job that need to be re-entered in Cloud.

Do I need to add double quotes around the text or not in the parameter strings?
Including passwords?

It isn't clear whether quotes are also required in web.
Some of my parameters are published with quotes and some without.

Comment: you have to put "http" also try to print the url in a tjava to see

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
My challenge was that everything worked in my local Talend Studio.
But not when executed via Cloud on the RemoteEngine.
AND the remote engine was configured on the same machine as my Talend Studio.

The problem was...
I had quoted my context variable values.
Thinking they were the same as when setting variables in tSetGlobalVar and the likes.
THIS IS INCORRECT.

Context variables must not be quoted in local Talend Studio or in Cloud.
Removing the double quotes resolved my problem.

Again though, it was odd it even worked at all in the first place.